# Webpack dev server watch options aggregateTimout does not work

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I need to delay my webpack dev server for ten seconds so other file will be ready.

my conifg file is :

```
   "devServer": {
    "historyApiFallback": true,
    "hot": false,
    "inline": false,
    "watchOptions": {
        "aggregateTimeout": 10000
    }
```

As i understood, once any file changed, webpack server should wait ten seconds before creating my bundles but the delay did not work and webpack start bundling once i change the file.

Any suggestions ? :(

Answer (score 1):

I use webpack v5 with dev-server meet this problem,too.

Webpack-dev-server use [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) to watch file. I find the parameter `awaitWriteFinish` can slove this problem.Read the `@types\webpack-dev-server\index.d.ts`,finding that watchFiles can set the chokidar options:

```js
   /**
    * This option allows you to configure list of globs/directories/files
    * to watch for file changes.
    */
    watchFiles?: string | string[] | WatchFiles | Array<WatchFiles | string> | undefined;

    interface WatchFiles {
        options?: chokidar.WatchOptions | undefined;
        paths?: string[] | string | undefined;
    }
```

This wepack.config.js is work for me:

```js
  devServer: {
    static: './dist',
    hot:true,
    open:true,
    watchFiles: {
      options:{
        awaitWriteFinish:{
          stabilityThreshold:2000
        }
      },
      paths:['src/**/*']
    }
  },
```

---

I think `aggregateTimeout` is not work:[webpack-dev-server issues #1782](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1782)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `poll` options:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/#watchoptionspoll

```
  watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 400,
    poll: 1000
  },
```

As I understand it, then the `poll` defines the trigger interval for hot reload. The `aggregateTimeout` adds extra time after the `poll` has discovered changes.

So lets say you set the `poll` to 1000ms, and the `aggregateTimeout` to 400ms. This means that the dev-server polls the changes in a 1000ms interval, and when a change is found then a 400ms timeout is applied before the dev-server will hot reload.

Comment: Isn't that global though? It's not just confined to devserver

Comment: It is aggregated to the module.exports so yes it is not confined to devserver.